# Create a table with specified column widths and centre spacing in tabularx

Tags: tables, tabularx

I would like to create a table where I can adjust the overall width of the table, hence the tabularx environment. However I am having difficulty in configuring my tables such that I can control:

1. The individual width of each column.
2. Centre each column.

This is the code I am using:

```
\documentclass[15pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabularx}{\textwidth}{p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{1.5cm}p{2.5cm}p{1.5cm}}\toprule\\[0.09ex]
Modelling & Reference & $\mu_{s}$ & Modelling & Outcome \\ Noise RMS &  Input Noise & & Time Duration \\ [2ex] \midrule\\ [0.5ex]
Optimal (0.3)& & 0.5 & Stopped once converged & Converged \\ [2ex]
0.05 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Failed to converge \\ [2ex]
 0.1 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.15 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.2 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.25 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.3 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.35 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.4 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.45 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
 0.5 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [0.5ex]\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabularx}
\end{table}
```

I have deliberately kept the second column empty for now. Any help on this is greatly appreciated as I have been trying to solve this for hours (including searching similar posts on tex stack exchange) to no avail. Thanks.

Comment: `tabularx` adjusts the width of the,  table by adjusting the width of `X` columns but you have none, so it can do nothing useful here just use `tabular` and `>{\centering\arraybackslash}p{1.5cm}` for centred columns

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You can have a look at [our starter guide](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/1436) to familiarize yourself further with our format.

Comment: You could also use \resizebox.

Answer (score 2):

You don't need `tabularx` if you don't use its `X` columns which adjust their width according to the available space.

You probably just need a new column type `M` defined in this way:

```
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
```

You don't also need to use different rows for long cells, since they are wrapped into new lines automatically.

MWE:

```
\documentclass[twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\newcolumntype{M}[1]{>{\centering\arraybackslash}m{#1}}
\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular}{M{1.7cm}M{1.5cm}M{1.5cm}M{2.5cm}M{2cm}}
\toprule
Modelling Noise RMS & Reference Input Noise & $\mu_{s}$ & Modelling Time Duration & Outcome \\
\midrule\\ [0.5ex]
Optimal (0.3)& & 0.5 & Stopped once converged & Converged \\ [2ex]
0.05 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Failed to converge \\ [2ex]
 0.1 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.15 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.2 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.25 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.3 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.35 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.4 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.45 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
 0.5 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [0.5ex]\\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

Output

[image]

As a side note, `15pt` is not a valid option for the `report` class.

Answer (score 2):

Here is a variant:

```
\documentclass[12pt,twoside]{report}
\usepackage{amsfonts}
\usepackage{tabularx, booktabs}
\usepackage{siunitx}
\usepackage{array}
\usepackage{ragged2e}
\newcolumntype{P}[1]{>{\Centering\arraybackslash}p{#1}}

\begin{document}
\begin{table}[h!]
\centering
\begin{tabular*}{\linewidth}{@{\extracolsep{\fill}}S[table-format=1.2]P{1.4cm}
                            S[table-format=1.2]P{2.5cm}P{1.8cm}}\toprule
{Modelling} & Reference & {$\mu_{s}$} & Modelling & Outcome \\ 
{Noise RMS} &  Input Noise & & Time Duration \\ [2ex] \midrule
{Optimal (0.3)}& & 0.5 & Stopped once converged & Converged \\ [2ex]
0.05 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Failed to converge \\ [2ex]
 0.1 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.15 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.2 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.25 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.3 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.35 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.4 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
0.45 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ [2ex]
 0.5 & & 0.25 & $n=10000$ & Destabilised \\ \bottomrule
\end{tabular*}
\end{table}
\end{document}
```

[image]